# Uniform Integrability and Exponential Tightness

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-integrability

I would like to know if the following idea (for which i didn't find references) is correct or not.

Let $\mu_n$ be an exponentially tight sequence of non negative measure i.e. such that there exists a sequence of compact $K_t$ such that for any $n$ $$ \mathbb{P}(\mu_n \notin K_t) \le e^{-nt}$$
Suppose that we are in the case that for every test function $\phi\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, $0<\mu_n(\phi)\le ||\phi||_{\infty}\mu_n(1)$, so I can easily study $\mu_n(1)$ which does not need to be finite.

My idea: the exponential tightness implies  the uniform integrability

$$\mathbb{E}(\mu^n(1)\mid\mu^n(1)>k)=\int_k^\infty dt\mathbb{P}(\mu_n(1)>t)\le \int_k^\infty dt e^{-nt}=\frac{1}{n}e^{-nk}.$$

Therefore for every $\epsilon>0, \,\exists\, k\in[0,\infty)$ such that
$$\sup_n\mathbb{E}(\mu^n(1)\mid\mu^n(1)>k)\le \sup_n \frac{1}{n}e^{-nk}<\epsilon$$

which gives the uniform integrability.

Is it correct or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I think your calculation of the conditional expectation is wrong. When you condition on the event that the random variable is larger than k, should the conditional expectation be larger than k as well? Your formula calculates the expectation of $\max[X-k, 0]$. Please see this post [Find expected value using CDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487348/expected-value-of-a-random-variable-by-integrating-1-cdf-when-lower-limit-a-n).

I suppose what you need to calculate is $E[X1_{\{X\ge k\}}]$.

Comment: Please instead of asking to see this post you can write using mathjax what to do